# Nestjs Error: Failed to execute command: npm install --silent I

Tags: ubuntu, nestjs

I tried to install a new nest project via cli for the first time and it abort after a few seconds after choosing the package manager.
Error: Failed to execute command: npm install --silent

I tried workarounds from here and github, but none was working

I got it running by

```
nest new test-project
cd test-project
npm install @types/jest@27.0.1
npm install
```

But that can not be the way, on a standard Ubuntu 20.04 maching with node v14.17.5 and npm 7.20.6 right?

Comment: looks like a bug on https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli Maybe with npm 7.20 (see [this](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/1277#issuecomment-895458385))

Comment: Not sure. ... maybe. I actually updated npm from 6 to 7, before I installed nest, to make sure, I do not get errors :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue with node v14, npm 8.10
I updated to node **v16.13.0**, **npm 8.1.4** and the project creation works fine both with package managers npm or yarn.

Comment: That did the trick. A while ago I installed nvm for managing node, because I noticed, that upgrading node on Ubuntu has its quirks.
So I installed a fresh nestjs with node v16.13 and it works.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Its a permission issue.

just run `sudo nest new project-name`

That should do it.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't I need then always need sudo permissions, to save or do anything?
Never needed to sudo in any similar framework so far.